# get time until hour in user timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to get the time until 12:00 AM in the users timezone. How can I do this in rails?

I want to get the time until 12:00 AM and then add that time to the current time in rails to store it in the database because I want to have a field with the GMT time at is the equivalent to 12:00 AM in the users timezone

I'm using this gem:

`gem 'time_difference', '~> 0.5.0'`

In order to get the time difference between two timestamps

```
TimeDifference.between(DateTime.now, created_at)
```

But I'm not sure how to get the time until 12:00 AM in the users timezone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a particular timezone, you can use Rails' tools for dealing with timezones to just directly find out when midnight is for a particular timezone. This example supposes you have a `time_zone` column on your User model with an appropriate value (e.g., `America/Chicago`, or anything else [Rails supports](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)):

```
midnight_for_user = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[user.time_zone].now.midnight.tomorrow
```

For example, I can use the same logic to find when midnight is for a person in New York:

```
pry(main)> Time.current
=> Thu, 05 Jan 2017 10:34:02 CST -06:00
pry(main)> ActiveSupport::TimeZone['America/New_York'].now.midnight.tomorrow
=> Fri, 06 Jan 2017 00:00:00 EST -05:00
```

Note that I'm looking for midnight tomorrow; remember that "midnight" for a given day is actually the very first minute of the day, not the last.

Comment: Robert, thank you so much. How can I use this to basically know how many hours from GMT (rails default time) is midnight for the user? That confuses the hell out of me. Thanks

Comment: You think I can convert now in seconds from GMT to users timezone and then find the difference in seconds between midnight in users timezone to now in users timezone and add those seconds to now in GMT? @RobertNubel

Comment: @Walker you could, but if you just want to store the user's midnight in GMT, saving `midnight_for_user` as calculated above to a model will automatically convert that time to GMT in the database. If you want to manually do the conversion, just call `midnight_for_user.utc` (remember that GMT and UTC are the same).

Comment: If you do want to know how far away the user's midnight is, `midnight_for_user - Time.now` will return the number of seconds until that time. Divide by 3600 to get hours.

Comment: I actually got it working like this `Time.now.in_time_zone(user.time_zone).midnight.tomorrow` so if I save that to the database it will save in gmt? That's exactly what I need

Comment: Yep, exactly. Note that when you pull the time out of the database, Rails will convert it to your app's timezone (it's still the same moment in time, just expressed differently; much like a temperature in Fahrenheit can be written in Celsius but it's still the same temperature). You can always call `.utc` to convert it to GMT manually.